# Conditional expectation with multiple conditioning

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

For any r.v.s $X$ and $Y$:

$$E(Y|E(Y|X)) = E(Y|X)$$

But I cannot seem to be able to prove this. I tried using Adam's Law with extra conditioning ($E(Y|X) = E(E(Y|X,Z)|Z)$) but I don't seem to get anywhere with it.

What I tried is the following:

$$g(X) = E(Y|X)$$
$$E(Y|g(X)) = E(E(Y|X,g(X))|g(X))$$
Since the event $X$ happened and $g(X)$ happened are equivalent, conditioning on both $X$ and $g(X)$ is the same as conditioning on only one of them.
Is there any intuitive interpretation of this ?

Does this also mean that conditioning on $X$ or any function $g$ of $X$ is the same ?

Comment: In general, conditioning on $X$ is not the same as conditioning on $g(X)$.  But in this formula it works.  One way to prove is using the definition: Show that $E[Y|X]$ satisfies the properties required to be a (version of a) conditional expectation of $Y$ given $E[Y|X]$: (i) Is $E[Y|X]$ in fact $\sigma(E[Y|X])$-measurable? (ii) For any event $A \in \sigma(E[Y|X])$ does it hold $E[E[Y|X]1_A] = E[Y1_A]$?

Comment: @Michael thanks for taking your time. Would you mind providing me a link or an explanation to what $\sigma(E[Y|X])$ -measurable means ? I'm learning probability theory from Introduction to Probability by Blitzstein but I did not encounter this definition before ?

Comment: Does $\sigma(E[Y|X)$ means that the result of the function is a random variable ?

Comment: You can look at "expectation given a random variable" or "expectation given a sigma algebra" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation  If you are not using measure theory then you can think of "$\sigma(Z)$-measurable" to mean "is a pure function of $Z$."  What definition of conditional expectation do you have?

Comment: My definition is the following: Let $g(x) = E(Y|X=x)$ then the conditional expectation of Y given X, denoted $E(Y|X)$ is defined to be the r.v. g(X).

Comment: I think I do understand the expectation given a random variable although I'm not sure I can connect your reasoning to my question in a comprehensive way.

Comment: $\sigma(E(Y|X)$ measurable on a probability space means that the outcome of the function is a r.v which is the case for $E(Y|X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the Tower Property of Conditional Expectations, which asserts that if $\mathcal F_1\subset\mathcal F_2$ then
$$
E[E[Y|\mathcal F_1]|\mathcal F_2] = E[E[Y|\mathcal F_2]|\mathcal F_1] = E[Y|\mathcal F_1].
$$
Use the second of these equalities, with $\mathcal F_1=\sigma(E[Y|X])$ and $\mathcal F_2=\sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

The argument you already have is a pretty good non-measure theory argument.  I will just formalize that below, it may help to give confidence about some details.

Using your argument structure: Let $g(X)=E[Y|X]$.  Then
\begin{align}
E[Y|g(X)] &\overset{(a)}{=} E[E[Y|g(X),X]|g(X)]\\
&\overset{(b)}{=} E[E[Y|X]|g(X)]\\
&=E[g(X)|g(X)]\\
&\overset{(c)}{=}g(X)
\end{align}
where (a) uses the law of iterated expectations; (b) uses $E[Y|g(X),X]=E[Y|X]$; (c) uses $E[Z|Z]=Z$ for any random variable $Z$. $\Box$

---

The step (b) more closely examined is:
$$E[Y|g(X),X]=E[Y|X]$$
and this intuitively means that if we already know $X$, then the additional information $g(X)$ adds nothing new.

---

Notes:

- Conditioning on $X$ is generally not the same as conditioning on $g(X)$, but it works in this particular problem.
- A measure-theory derivation could be given along the lines of my first comment on your answer.  You can also justify $E[Y|g(X),X]=E[Y|X]$ more formally by measure theory ("the sigma algebra generated by $(g(X),X)$ is the same as the sigma algebra generated by $X$").
- A formal measure theory definition talks about "versions of" a conditional expectation, and I do not go into such detail in this answer (some people may want to replace my equalities with equalities that hold "with probability 1").

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, from a non-measure theory perspective (Which I understand in more detail). The second step (b) was the one that I was doubtful, although it does makes sense intuitively. Is there somewhere in practice where conditioning on X and $E(Y|X)$ is used ?
Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Given the level of formality of the book, I think what the exercise is going for is primarily *conceptual*. I.e., what does the below conditioning mean:

E(Y|E(Y|X), X) | X = x

This represents the expectation of Y, if I know what the expectation of Y given X would be... and now I also know X! So I'm exactly in the situation where I know X, and I know what the expectation of Y given X is, which is what the expectation of Y given that conditional information is. I.e., E(Y|X). And then you Adam's Law it up via taking out what's known given X, which E(Y|X) is as that's a function of X.

(So it's more specific than just any g(X) - its essential to the argument that g(X) = E(Y|X) in particular.)